# selenium-Python, how to click the logout image button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

the html is below:

```
<li class="logout"> <a href="#/logout"><img src="resources/img/logout.png"/></a></li>
```

python is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src='resources/images/logout.png')]/parent::a").click()
```

it giving error as below

```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src='resources/images/logout.png')]/parent::a").click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 221, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[contains(@src=\'resources/images/logout.png\')]/parent::a"}' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpu3t8lf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8860)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///tmp/tmpu3t8lf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:396)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather use css selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.logout>a').click()
```

See [`find_element_by_css_selector`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_css_selector).

---

If you want use xpath, use following xpath expression (There's a typo in the code: `images` -> `img`):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[img/@src="resources/img/logout.png"]').click()
```

Comment: No need for two nested square brackets, you can just use `//a[img/@src="resources/img/logout.png"]` as XPath.

Comment: @Robin, You're right. Thank you for enlightening me. I updated the answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='resources/images/logout.png']/parent::a").click()`